# How do you open IE on specified monitor using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, multiple-monitors, vba

I have code to center a userform on the active monitor. The userform has an option to open a fullscreens IE window which takes the user to a site and performs some HTML parsing.  I would like to give the user the choice to open the IE window on the current or secondary monitor but I am not having luck finding any useful information online. The VBA I am using to open IE is shown below. Any pointers would be appreciated!

```
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim LoginAttempt As String
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.Navigate "www.gooogle.com”
```

Comment: Please use [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Maldred, i dont see how this helps... i got the question by just reading the title, it is just i cannot answer it withou using google and testing around ;-)

Comment: Well you changed your question, it seemed like before you were just asking for code. Unfortunately, I am unable to answer this question, however a quick Google search came up with this! [Maybe this can be of help?](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27867541/How-Can-I-Specify-what-Screen-to-Open-an-Application-on.html) Also, try posting your code that you're attempting to add it to and maybe some one else here with more knowledge can be of better assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most optimal way going about this, but it works for my application.

```
Sub openBrowser()
Dim ie As Object
Dim Answ As Variant

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Answ = MsgBox("Do you want to open on scondary monitor?", vbYesNo)
If Answ = vbYes Then ie.Left = 0
ie.fullscreen = True
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://www.google.com"

End Sub
```

This works for me. Hope it helps you out

/T

Comment: I had to change the ie.Left value from 0 to 1060 to move the window to my next monitor but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you T!